# Does anyone know how to sort out this timeout error?

Tags: python, ssl, smtplib

The code I found at https://github.com/thepycoach/automation/blob/main/Send%20Emails.py gives an error code which I don't know how to avoid.

I tried: https://github.com/thepycoach/automation/blob/main/Send%20Emails.py.
Note:
I changed the following values and what I changed them to:
*email_sender(my other email)
*email_password(my other email's password)
*465 (different port)
Here is the code:

```
import smtplib
import ssl
from email.message import EmailMessage

# Define email sender and receiver
email_sender = 'write-email-here'
email_password = 'write-password-here'
email_receiver = 'write-email-receiver-here'

# Set the subject and body of the email
subject = 'Check out my new video!'
body = """
I've just published a new video on YouTube: https://youtu.be/2cZzP9DLlkg
"""

em = EmailMessage()
em['From'] = email_sender
em['To'] = email_receiver
em['Subject'] = subject
em.set_content(body)

# Add SSL (layer of security)
context = ssl.create_default_context()

# Log in and send the email
with smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465, context=context) as smtp:
    smtp.login(email_sender, email_password)
    smtp.sendmail(email_sender, email_receiver, em.as_string())
```

It gave a TimeOutError of:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\nooneinparticular\sendimages.py", line 26, in <module>
    with smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 110, context=context) as smtp:
  File "c:\Python3.9.9\lib\smtplib.py", line 1050, in __init__
    SMTP.__init__(self, host, port, local_hostname, timeout,
  File "c:\Python3.9.9\lib\smtplib.py", line 255, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "c:\Python3.9.9\lib\smtplib.py", line 341, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "c:\Python3.9.9\lib\smtplib.py", line 1056, in _get_socket
    new_socket = super()._get_socket(host, port, timeout)
  File "c:\Python3.9.9\lib\smtplib.py", line 312, in _get_socket
    return socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout,
  File "c:\Python3.9.9\lib\socket.py", line 844, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "c:\Python3.9.9\lib\socket.py", line 832, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a while or an established connection failed because the connected host has failed to respond
```

Comment: This is a problem with the host. Try `telnet smtp.gmail.com 465` and enter `ehlo me` as a command, and you'll see it closes the connection. According to `host gmail.com` email for gmail is handled by (among others) smtp.gmail.com and if you telnet to that on the default SMTP port of 25, you get a reply to your `EHLO` command. (Close the connection with `QUIT`.) So try switching  `smtplib.SMTP_SSL` to `smtplib.SMTP` and change the server and port as above.

Comment: Sorry, I am very new to coding please can you simplify that for me.

Comment: I think that comment from @Robert is erroneous. Your code works correctly for me; if you're getting a timeout that suggests that something in your network may be blocking connections to port 465.